# You are being redirected Javascript is required python requests_html

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to navigate to specific url https://www.moi.gov.kw/main/eservices/residence/fines-enquiry and in the search box I input `268101704418` then click on Enquire button.
Trying to follow the Network tab in Chrome developer tools I found the link like that
`https://www.moi.gov.kw/mfservices/immigration-fines/residency/268101704418` and I tried to use python requests_html and used headers like that

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
s = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://www.moi.gov.kw/mfservices/immigration-fines/residency/268101704418'

def get_links(url):
    r = s.get(url)
    print(r.content)

get_links(url)
```

But I got this response

```
b"<html><title>You are being redirected...</title>\n<noscript>Javascript is required. Please enable javascript before you are allowed to see this page.</noscript>\n<script>var s={},u,c,U,r,i,l=0,a,e=eval,w=String.fromCharCode,sucuri_cloudproxy_js='',S='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';L=S.length;U=0;r='';var A='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';for(u=0;u<64;u++){s[A.charAt(u)]=u;}for(i=0;i<L;i++){c=s[S.charAt(i)];U=(U<<6)+c;l+=6;while(l>=8){((a=(U>>>(l-=8))&0xff)||(i<(L-2)))&&(r+=w(a));}}e(r);</script></html>\n"
```

Any help how to deal with the JavaScript is required issue?

Comment: U have to use silinium to render js

Comment: So there is no other way except using selenium?!

Comment: i think scrapy freamwork can also handl the prblm